# Is stitching module of OpenCV able to stitch images taken from a parallel motion camera?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, panoramas, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I was wondering if the stitching(http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html) module of OpenCV is able to stitch the images taken from a camera that is in parallel motion to the plane which is being photographed ?

I know that generally all the panoramic stitching tools assume that the center of the camera is fixed and that the camera only experiences motion such as pan or pitch.

I was thinking if I can use this module to stitch the image taken from a camera which moves parallel to the plane. The idea is to create a panoramic map of the ground.

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for the record.

The current stitching utility in open cv does not consider translation of the camera and only assumes that camera is rotated around its axis. So, basically it tries to create and project images on cylindrical or spherical canvas.

But in my case, I needed to consider the translation motion while predicting the camera transformation and this is not possible with the existing stitching utility of opencv.

All these observations are made based on the code walk-through of opencv code and through trials.

But, you are welcome to correct this information or to add more information so that this can be a useful future reference.

Regards