# How can I stitch images from video cameras in real time?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching, opencv3.0, opencv-stitching

I use 4 stationary cameras. Cameras **do not move relative to each other**. And I want to stitch video images from them into the one video image **in real time**.

I use for this OpenCV 2.4.10, and [`cv:stitcher`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/high_level.html#stitcher) class, like this:

```cpp
// use 4 video-cameras
cv::VideoCapture cap0(0), cap1(1), cap2(2), cap3(3);

bool try_use_gpu = true;    // use GPU
cv::Stitcher stitcher = cv::Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
stitcher.setWarper(new cv::CylindricalWarperGpu());
stitcher.setWaveCorrection(false);
stitcher.setSeamEstimationResol(0.001);
stitcher.setPanoConfidenceThresh(0.1);

//stitcher.setSeamFinder(new cv::detail::GraphCutSeamFinder(cv::detail::GraphCutSeamFinderBase::COST_COLOR_GRAD));
stitcher.setSeamFinder(new cv::detail::NoSeamFinder());
stitcher.setBlender(cv::detail::Blender::createDefault(cv::detail::Blender::NO, true));
//stitcher.setExposureCompensator(cv::detail::ExposureCompensator::createDefault(cv::detail::ExposureCompensator::NO));
stitcher.setExposureCompensator(new cv::detail::NoExposureCompensator());


std::vector<cv::Mat> images(4);
cap0 >> images[0];
cap1 >> images[1];
cap2 >> images[2];
cap3 >> images[3];

// call once!
cv::Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.estimateTransform(images);


while(true) {

    // **lack of speed, even if I use old frames**
    // std::vector<cv::Mat> images(4);
    //cap0 >> images[0];
    //cap1 >> images[1];
    //cap2 >> images[2];
    //cap3 >> images[3];

    cv::Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.composePanorama(images, pano_result);
}
```

I get only 10 FPS (frame per seconds), but I need 25 FPS.
How can I accelerate this example?

When I use `stitcher.setWarper(new cv::PlaneWarperGpu());` then I get a very enlarged image, this I do not need.

I need **only - Translations**.

For example, I'm ready to don't use:

- Perspective transformation
- Scale operations
- and may be even Rotations

How can I do it? Or how can I get from `cv::Stitcher stitcher` parameters `x,y` of translations for each of images?

**UPDATE - profiling in MSVS 2013 on Windows 7 x64:**
[image]

Comment: What kind of machine are you using? Do you have tbb enabled? Besides, can you provide a few images as example to be stitched together?

Comment: @Antonio 8 GB RAM + CPU (Intel Core i5 760 - 4 Cores) + GPU (nVidia GeForce GTX 970 - 1664 Cores). TBB disabled. OpenCV 2.4.10 compiled with CUDA 6.5 and disabled OpenMP/TBB.

Comment: TBB might help by multithreading the process... For which system did you build, and with which build tools? Also, one quick thing to try is to put the image array declaration/definition out of the while loop. (You are allocating and deallocating at each cycle). I suggest that you put some timer around your stitching function, to check that that function call is the actual bottleneck.

Comment: @Antonio GCC 4.7.2 + CUDA 6.5 on Linux x86_64 Debian 7 (Wheezy). **Fixed:** I  put the image array declaration/definition out of the while loop.

Comment: Could you test if that gives any speed improvement? Putting the timer I mentioned before would be very important, to exclude the possibility you are stuck in reading frames. Do you get 25fps if you skip completely the stitching?

Comment: I would be also curious to know how your cameras are plugged to the machine (network cards? Usb 2? Usb 3?), what is the resolution and if you have greyscale or color images.

Comment: @Antonio No, lack of speed, even if I use old frames on each iteration. I use 640x480 RGB frames. I added profiling information, from MSVS 2013 on Windows.

Comment: Fantastic profiling! In the meantime, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18529327/2436175) there is some useful information: if you only want translation, probably stitching is not what you need. You say translation is sufficient: are your cameras all on the same axis and plane, and oriented perpendicularly to this axis?

Comment: Another thing: in OpenCV 2.4 don't you have to use [GpuMat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/data_structures.html?highlight=gpumat#gpu-gpumat) instead of Mat? I think it might be so far you haven't been using the gpu...

Comment: If you only need translations and the cameras don't move, why can't you precompute the position of each source video on the target and then later on just put them there and blend them? Is it because you get seams?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446694/opencv-stitching-images-from-google-maps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`cv::Stitcher` is fairly slow. If your cameras definitely don't move relative to one another and the transformation is as simple as you say, you should be able to overlay the images onto a blank canvas simply by chaining [homographies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVJeJMWZcq8).

The following is somewhat mathematical - if this isn't clear I can write it up properly using LaTeX, but SO doesn't support pretty maths :)

You have a set of 4 cameras, from left to right, `(C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4)`, giving a set of 4 images `(I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4)`.

To transform from `I_1` to `I_2`, you have a 3x3 transformation matrix, called a homography. We'll call this `H_12`. Similarly for `I_2` to `I_3` we have `H_23` and for `I_3` to `I_4` you'll have `H_34`.

You can pre-calibrate these homographies in advance using the standard method ([point matching between the overlapping cameras](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)).

You'll need to create a blank matrix, to act as the canvas. You can guess the size of this (4*image_size would suffice) or you can take the top-right corner (call this `P1_tr`) and transform it by the three homographies, giving a new point at the top-right of the panorama, `PP_tr` (the following assumes that `P1_tr` has been converted to a matrix):

```
PP_tr = H_34 * H_23 * H_12 * P1_tr'
```

What this is doing, is taking `P1_tr` and transforming it first into camera 2, then from `C_2` to `C_3` and finally from `C_3` to `C_4`

You'll need to create one of these for combining images 1 and 2, images 1,2 and 3 and finally images 1-4, I'll refer to them as `V_12`, `V_123` and `V_1234` respectively.

Use the following to warp the image onto the canvas:

```
cv::warpAffine(I_2, V_12, H_12, V_12.size( ));
```

Then do the same with the next images:

```
cv::warpAffine(I_3, V_123, H_23*H_12, V_123.size( ));
cv::warpAffine(I_4, V_1234, H_34*H_23*H_12, V_1234.size( ));
```

Now you have four canvases, all of which are the width of the 4 combined images, and with one of the images transformed into the relevant place on each.

All that remains is to merge the transformed images onto eachother. This is easily achieved using regions of interest.

Creating the ROI masks can be done **in advance**, before frame capture begins.

Start with a blank (zeros) image the same size as your canvases will be. Set the leftmost rectangle the size of `I_1` to white. This is the mask for your first image. We'll call it `M_1`.

Next, to get the mask for the second transformed image, we do

```
cv::warpAffine(M_1, M_2, H_12, M_1.size( ));
cv::warpAffine(M_2, M_3, H_23*H_12, M_1.size( ));
cv::warpAffine(M_3, M_4, H_34*H_23*H_12, M_1.size( ));
```

To bring all the images together into one panorama, you do:

```
cv::Mat pano = zeros(M_1.size( ), CV_8UC3);
I_1.copyTo(pano, M_1);
V_12.copyTo(pano, M_2): 
V_123.copyTo(pano, M_3): 
V_1234.copyTo(pano, M_4):
```

What you're doing here is [copying the relevant area of each canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479265/apply-mask-to-image-in-opencv) onto the output image, pano - a fast operation.

You should be able to do all this on the GPU, substituting `cv::gpu::Mat`'s for `cv::Mats` and `cv::gpu::warpAffine` for its non-GPU counterpart.

Comment: To make this approach even more efficient, you could precalculate the affine warping maps, since they are constant, and use `cv::remap` (see [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#remap)) which is much faster than `cv::warpAffine`.

Comment: Nice, yes that's a very good idea. I've actually done that in the past and it works very well, just didn't spring to mind when I was writing out the above.

Comment: @n00dle Thank you very much! But you said, that I must find: **3x3** transformation matrix, called a **homography**, and use: `cv::warpAffine();`, but as I know `warpAffine();` uses **affine transformation matrix (2x3)**. Does it mean that I must use `warpAffine();` after `estimateRigidTransform();`? Or do I must use `warpPerspective();` after `findHomography();`? And how can I get `map1, map2` for `ramap();` from homography which I found by using `findHomography();`?

Comment: Apologies, I mixed up the two. In this case you say you need only a translation in which case the affine matrix, estimated with estimateRigidTransform would do the trick. If you find this doesn't represent the full transformation (i.e. the overlaid images look a bit out of line in a non-uniform way) you may wish to use the homography. I'm not 100% on the remap question - I think I have the code at work, but won't be back in until Wednesday as it's the easter break here in the UK. I would advise looking at initUndistortRectifyMap()as I feel that may have something to do with it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation. I'm trying something very similar. What bothers me is that whn doing homographies is that you get that big useless black area around your image. Is there any way to only obtain the usefull part of the image? (I'd rather not use for loops for performance reasons). Here is what I mean: original image: http://imgur.com/a/wUlwE , to which I then apply a hompgraphy transformation to get a birdview: http://imgur.com/a/49Ee5 (note the big unwanted black area in my window), and I'd like: http://imgur.com/a/gCoEC (I manually cut it out) without losing too much data

Comment: You can work out the position of the corners of your original image (lets call it `A`) in the new image space (`B`) quite easily once you've got the 3x3 homography (`H`). For some corner `A = (x,y)`, express it in homogenous coordinates `A' = (x, y, 1)` and do `B' = HA'`. Using this will give you the four corner points in the new image and so you can crop it as you choose based on those.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I leave this answer just as documentation of what was tried, as the method I suggested doesn't seem to work, while apparently the GPU is already in use when using cv::Mat.

---

Try using [`gpu::GpuMat`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/data_structures.html?#gpu-gpumat):

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> images(4);
std::vector<gpu::GpuMat> gpuImages(4);
gpu::GpuMat pano_result_gpu;
cv::Mat pano_result; 
bool firstTime = true;

[...] 

cap0 >> images[0];
cap1 >> images[1];
cap2 >> images[2];
cap3 >> images[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   gpuImages[i].upload(images[i]);
if (firstTime) {
    cv::Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.estimateTransform(gpuImages);
    firstTime = false;
    }
cv::Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.composePanorama(gpuImages, pano_result_gpu);
pano_result_gpu.download(pano_result);
```

Comment: When I use `cv::gpu::GpuMat` instead of `cv::Mat` in `estimateTransform();` or in `composePanorama();` then I get an error on Windows 7x64 + OpenCV 2.4.9: *OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (func != 0) in cv::resize, file C:\opencv_2.4.9\o
pencv\sources\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp, line 1980*

Comment: @Alex That at least proves the GPU was not used before :) Please update your question and post the code you find in `C:\opencv_2.4.9\o pencv\sources\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp` around line 1980

Comment: But MSVS 2013 result of profiling, which I added to my question show me that GPU used many times :) Code from error is here:  http://pastebin.com/VVN1gMK2

Comment: @Alex I saw I had a copy of 2.4.9, but that's difficult to debug... Who is calling the `cv::resize` with apparently a wrong interpolation attribute? Maybe after all using gpu::GpuMat is not the correct way.